# QFIELD How to close the attribute table to be able to see the create icon again

Tags: qfield

I am trialing QField and when I click on a point it shows the table where I can view the attributes or edit them.

How do I close this window/tab so I can view the create feature pencil icon again?

I am sure it is obvious...

Comment: When you launch QField it is in browse mode. In this mode you press back and the attribute table is cleared. When in digitize mode this doesn't seem to work as pressing back quits the app. Reverting to browse mode and pressing back also quits the app. It might be a bug.

Comment: I have the same problem - it is very frustrating as you cannot see the screen. As the Techie_Gus says the only way to escape is the back button however this seems to stop working at times. I have had it stop working on both Browse and Digitise modes. The only way to escape from the bug is to close the app and then re-open it. The back button then seems to work for a while but will then stop again...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134508)

Comment: I think the bugginess described by Squezz above persists.

Answer (score 1):

In order to close the attribute panel you're talking about, you should press back/return button of your **device**. This can be a physical button depending on your model.

Comment: This answer seems to be correct in theory, however, as per Squezz's comment following the question above, there may be a bug that means this process does not always work. I too experience this problem, i.e. that pushing "back" does not get you out of the attribute table/form, and only presents you with the possibility of pushing it once more to exit QField, though this also doesn't always work, and you need to restart the whole app.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround which worked for me:

Make sure that the layer which has its attributes opened in the attribute panel is selected/activated in the layers panel.

On the attribute panel click on the attribute (e.g. the id). Then click back on the attribute panel. (look for the symbol < )

Now you should be able to click on the devices back/return button and the attribute panel will close.

This approach was described here: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/262